# Removable singularity of exp(f(z))

Tags: complex-analysis

I have already classified the case when $f(z)$ has a non removable singularity then what about the nature of the singularity of $e^{f(z)}$ ?? [ - as in the exercise of Gamelin's book]

Now my question is : if $f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z_{0}$ (say,) does $e^{f(z)}$ have a removable singularity at  $z_{0}$??? ( i.e. Prove OR Disprove)

What I am thinking is to use the necessary & sufficient criteria of having removable singularity,i.e. we have $Lt_{z \to z_{0}} |z-z_{0}| |f(z)| = 0$. Using this can we show that : $Lt_{z \to z_{0}} |z-z_{0}| |e^{f(z)}| = 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Riemann's theorem on removable singularities:

Assume that a holomorphic function $f:U\to \mathbb C$ has an isolated singularity at $p\in U$. Then the singularity is removable if and only if $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $p$.

In our case, if $f$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$, it is bounded around $z_0$. Therefore, $e^f$ is also bounded around $z_0$, which implies that it has a removable singularity there.